# How to solve virtual host issue

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have multiple sites all setup the same as below except "bk" has something else in it's place...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost bk:80>
  ServerName bk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/bk.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and I get these errors when restarting apache:

```
[Mon Jan 17 10:28:56 2011] [error] VirtualHost bk:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Mon Jan 17 10:28:56 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost bk:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

I don't get it... the other 2 sites I have virtual host configurations for this exact same way don't throw any errors

**update**

One error message fixed - here's where I'm at now..

```
<VirtualHost bk:80>
  ServerName bk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/bk.com/
</VirtualHost>

[Mon Jan 17 10:28:56 2011] [error] VirtualHost bk:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NameVirtualHost directive usually should be used only once in server config, an usually it looks like "NameVirtualHost *:80", which means "serve virtualhosts on all available IP addresses". In most cases, you don't care about IP address on which request was accepted as long as it contains "Host:" field.

Comment: That took care of the "has no virtual hosts" error, but I still get the other thing about mixing ports

Comment: <VirtualHost> directives should take exactly the same argument that was specified in "NameVirtualHost" directive.

Comment: I've made that adjustment and it got rid of the error, thanks.  When I access `http://bk/` it throws PHP errors for another site, not the one specified in this virtual host... any ideas why that is?  This virtual host only contains HTML, no PHP

Comment: Can you show all your virtualhosts?